# Yii2 Multiple Variables to be passed in URL

Tags: url, yii2, yii2-advanced-app

I want to generate URL's that can handle multiple parameters. 
Eg:

```
    www.example.com/product/index?brand=brand-name,
    www.example.com/product/index?category=category-name,
```

I want the url be like :

```
   www.example.com/brand-name,
   www.example.com/category-name
```

Tried some url rules,but it doesn't work.

```
'rules' => [
       [
        'pattern' => '<brand:\w+(-\w+)*>/<category:\w+(-\w+)*>',
        'route' => 'product/index',
        'defaults' => [
                   'brand' => null,
                   'category' => null,
              ]
      ]
]
```

This is my reference :

[Reference question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33607945/multiple-variables-to-be-passed-in-url-yii2)

Comment: If either have to add some way at the target action to tell if given name is category or brand or to make these two urls explicitly different (like with prefix or something).

Comment: Is there any other way to handle with same action? I tried the above rule, but it not working with two parameter

Comment: The problem is how the system should know that if you enter `www.example.com/abc` `abc` is brand and not a category or other way around.

Answer (score 0):

To do this you will have to stick to the prefixed version. So the brand param should always be prefixed with `brand-` and the category always with `category-`. Otherwise there is no way to tell what is what.

Add the following rules. This will put everything that matches `brand-\w+` in the `brand` argument and pass it to `product/index`. Same for category.

```
'<brand:brand-\w+>' => 'product/index',
'<category:category-\w+>' => 'product/index',
```

To see that it works

```
public function actionIndex($brand = null, $category = null) {
    echo "Brand: $brand<br />";
    echo "Category: $category<br />";

    echo Url::toRoute(['dev/index', 'brand' => 'brand-name']) . '<br />';
    echo Url::toRoute(['dev/index', 'category' => 'category-name']) . '<br />';
}
```